# Flutter align widgets in an expanded container, to the top left and bottom right?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a layout in my application which comprises of some text and a timestamp. I'm looking to have the timestamp (clock icon in the picture) be at the bottom left corner of the expanded widget, while the text ("what" string in the picture) should start from the top right.

**Representation:**

```
|text|              |
|    -----------    |
|    empty space    |
|    -----------    |
|              |time|
```

Currently, what I managed below have them aligned to the extreme left and right, but they seem to be constrained by the Column widget and as such, are aligned to the centre of the widget. And I cannot seem to get expanded to work within another Expanded.

[image]

**Widget code:**

```
return new Container(
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 60.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
                onPressed: () => null,
              ),
              new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: new Text("1231"),
              ),
              new MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 60.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                onPressed: () => null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          new Expanded(
            // child: new Container(
            // padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: new Column(
              // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: new Text("what"),
                ),

                // "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."),
                new Align(
                  // padding: new EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Container(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: new Icon(
                          Icons.access_time,
                          size: 12.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Container(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                        child: new Text("1 hr"),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // ),
          ),
          new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 60.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.save, size: 20.0),
                onPressed: () => null,
              ),
              new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: new Text("8"),
              ),
              new MaterialButton(
                minWidth: 60.0,
                child: new Icon(Icons.comment, size: 20.0),
                onPressed: () => null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: could you put the image again? I can't see it

Comment: @diegoveloper here's a link: https://imgur.com/a/QwCBhpY

Answer (score 18):

try using **alignment: Alignment.bottomRight** as a named parameter of **Container** class

Answer (score 9):

Ok, so I modified your `Widget` and I added some Colors to the container to track the changes very easy:

```
        double maxHeight = 130.0;

    Widget _buildLeft() {
      return Container(
        height: maxHeight,
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new MaterialButton(
              minWidth: 60.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: new Text("1231"),
            ),
            new MaterialButton(
              minWidth: 60.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget _buildCenter() {
      return Expanded(
        child: Container(
          height: maxHeight,
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                child: new Text("what"),
                top: 0.0,
                left: 0.0,
              ),
              // "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0.0,
                right: 0.0,
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: new Icon(
                        Icons.access_time,
                        size: 12.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                      child: new Text("1 hr"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget _buildRight() {
      return Container(
        height: maxHeight,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            new MaterialButton(
              minWidth: 60.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.save, size: 20.0),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
            new Container(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: new Text("8"),
            ),
            new MaterialButton(
              minWidth: 60.0,
              child: new Icon(Icons.comment, size: 20.0),
              onPressed: () => null,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Container(
        child: new Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildLeft(),
            _buildCenter(),
            _buildRight(),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the result seems to be the same as my original code. I'm looking to have the expanded widget (tinted blue) fill the entire middle section both length and width, and have the text on the top-left, and the time on the bottom-left.

Comment: Thanks, that kinda fits my requirements but is there a way to make the height dynamic based on text size? Currently the text doesn't wrap around like it did before as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Container wrap the Align, This can stop Align from expanding itself

```dart
Container(
  color: darkBlue,
  child: Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    heightFactor: value,
    child: Container(
    // alignment: Alignment.center, //<--must not uncomment this
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
      color: Colors.red,
      child: child,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: In my case, I did not need add Align widget, I used the alignment property directly: `Expanded(child: Container(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: ...))`